# Pulling data from a different table if pertaining data is not available in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am novice to sql

I have a table1 with [month], [forecasted avg. temperature] as columns. I have another table2 with [month], [actual avg. temperature] as columns. Now for some dates, there is no records available in table one. In that case I would like to pull records from the table2 if I have available record in that table.

for example table 1 may have records from april to dec for a year say 2010. table 2 has the records for jan to dec for 2010 year. I would like to pull records from table 2 for the mising jan, feb, mar months records in table 1.

Any idea.  we are using sql server 2008

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
   [month], isnull([forecasted avg. temperature], [actual avg. temperature]) as temperature 
from 
   table2 left outer join table1 on table1.[month] = table2.[month]
```

UPDATE
per comment from Dems, I changed the query. The original post makes it sound as though table2 includes data for all months, so rather than a FULL JOIN, I just switched so it will pull all records from table2, and join if available to table1, continuing to use ISNULL for the temp.  If table2 does not include all data, then a FULL JOIN is necessary.

Comment: +0 : A `JOIN` is closest to what I think the OP asked (though it's a bit ambiguous) : Give value from T1 if it exists, else give the value from T2.  But you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` *(If there is no row in T1, your answer has nothing to JOIN T2 on to)*.  Then you'd need to ISNULL() on both fields.

Comment: That's an interesting piece of lateral thinking. I'm going to put this in my cunning plan box.

Answer (score 2):

```
select [month], [forecasted avg. temperature] as temperature from table1
union
select [month], [actual avg. temperature] as temperature from table2
```

Comment: If month is in both tables will different temps that will pull both out.

Comment: Mind you that scenario wasn't specifically mentioned.

Comment: If month is in both tables will different temps that will pull both out. Thats true. Now if there r duplicate values coming from both tables, then i need to retain only temperature values from table1

Answer (score 0):

One way is a union with outer join query

```
Select  [month], [forecasted avg. temperature] from Table1
Union
Select [month], [actual avg. temperature] From Table2
outer join Table1 on Table1.[Month] = Table2.Month
Where Table1.Month is null
```

Off the top of my head, and for Cthulu's sake give your tables and columns legal names.

If you want a friendlier name on output do something like

```
Select ForeCastAvgTemp As [forecasted avg. temperature] From Table1
```